# Complex conditional regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem with a regex,

Here is a sample of my data (http://regex101.com/r/rE3hO9/1) :

```
<M ID="9459" C="VSPH" S="I" T="2014-08-04T21:52:33. 0+02:00"><PS><P T="0">[P2000_DS13] vmserv01/vmserv01.vmdk</P><P T="0">29.22 GB</P><P T="0">30.00 GB</P></PS></M>
<M ID="9519" C="VSPH" S="I" T="2014-08-04T21:52:33. 0+02:00"><PS><P T="0">[P2000_DS15] vmserv02/vmserv02.vmdk</P><P T="0">15.20 GB</P><P T="0">15.20 GB</P><P T="0">100.00 GB</P></PS></M>
```

I need to isolate the name of the server ex :

```
<P T="0">[P2000_DS13] vmserv01/vmserv01.vmdk</P>
```

And its different values (there can be 0, 1, 2 or 3) like this :

```
   <P T="0">29.22 GB</P><P T="0">30.00 GB</P>
   <P T="0">30.00 GB</P>
```

So far i made this :

```
<M ID="[0-9]+" C="VSPH" S="I" T="(.*)"><PS><P T="(.*)">\[(.*)] (.*?)\/(.*)<\/P><P T="(.*)">(.*) GB<\/P><P T="(.*)">(.*) GB<\/P><P T="(.*)">(.*) GB<\/P><\/PS><\/M>
```

But it work well when i have 3 values, but it doesnt match when i only have 2 or 1.

Could you please give an hand with this.

Thanks

Comment: And what language will you use after?

Comment: I'd suggest you look into XML parsers instead.

Comment: Uhhhhhhm stop trying to break your script, because it looks like you have xml. Use an xml parser

Comment: in your regex link the first string input has no <P T="0">100.00 GB</P>.So the regex will not match the first entry but ony the second.

Comment: You're also matching a bunch of stuff you don't need which is why the regex is huge. If something this in-depth research an xml parser as @PeeHaa suggested

Comment: A better way is indeed to use DOMDocument (for example). However, I think you are looking for that: http://regex101.com/r/nT3fW0/3

Comment: I used a little less strict regex with named captured groups [here](http://regex101.com/r/rE3hO9/2). But it's still pretty messy.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need 2 regexes for this.

First you separate the `<M>` tags:

```
<M ID="[0-9]+" C="VSPH" S="I" T="[^"]+"><PS>(<P T="0">[^<]+</P>)+</PS></M>
```

Then for each match[1] you let this regex match every `<P>` tag inside, one by one:

```
<P T="0">[^<]+</P>
```

Comment: +1 It may be the better way, but it depends of the cases. Keep in mind that the regex engine is a machine (written in C and with a pre-analysis of the pattern to apply the best algorithms (cf: mastering regular expressions J.F.friedl (old edition free on the web))) to find occurences (and that it's optimized for this task). To be sure, you must compare it with a (well built) pattern that uses the `\G` feature (that is an anchor for the end of the last match, anchoring a pattern will increase the performances). All I want to say, It's depend of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted to use a regex and not a parser,

```
(?:<P(?!S)[^>]*>)([^<(GB$)]*)(?:<\/P>)
```

This isoloates the server name completely (the value of but not the tags).  If you want the tags, then this would work:

```
(<P(?!S)[^>]*>)([^<(GB$)]*)(<\/P>)
```

These assume that unwanted entries end with "GB".